# How to have different vertical alignment of multiple paragraphs in a table cell in composite mode?

Tags: itext

I have two paragraphs to be added to a PdfPCell. The first needs to be aligned to the top-left of the cell.
The second needs to be aligned to the bottom-right of the cell.

I'm adding them to the cell in composite mode so the alignment properties of the individual paragraphs will be used, but can't see how to align the second paragraph vertically to the bottom. Looks like Paragraph.setAlignment is only for horizontal, not vertical alignment? You can't combine them?

I'm aware that if necessary i can do it "the hard way" with events and can lay-out the paragraphs myself with ColumnText.
However, was hoping there was something simple and obvious that i've missed!
Have i?

Comment: Very good question, but I fear that this is a case where "the hard way" is the only way.

Comment: ok, no worries... "the hard way" it is. Thanks Bruno, appreciate the response.